# Is there option in any IDE to display available options for specific function?

Tags: editors, arguments, ide

Does any IDE support feature to show all available arguments for specific function?
For example instead just showing circle(nothing) like this:
[image]

To show something like this (similar like Visual Studio does with C#):
[image]

If Texmaker can't do this is there then any IDE to have that feature for LaTex?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. May be this is something you can ask the SW support of TeXmaker? This is not directly related to any TeX related issues per se.

Comment: Thanks.. :) It would be nice if you know any IDE to have that feature to tell, this annoys me to write something completely rote..

Comment: I am really sorry, I don't know of anything ATM that has influence on the document class. However, I know for a fact that `TeXstudio` can suggest preferences for `\usepackage{...}`. See: https://imgur.com/a/Fv4bWl4

Comment: @Hury Like C# IDEs, there are thousands of LaTeX IDEs, and no one uses them all. However, as I can see, none of the IDEs I know have that feature. (However you can always add `\documentclass{article}`, `\documentclass{report}`, etc. to the auto-complete list of your Texmaker.)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479706/how-to-disable-suggestions-when-typing-usepackage?noredirect=1#comment1212088_479706 Sublime is able to show such suggestions.

Comment: @samcarter Thanks man! This was driving me out.. 
PS. a little weird how at the same time someone does not want the same feature heh..

Comment: @HuryH You're welcome! Would you like to write a short self-answer so that future users with the same problem can benefit from your findings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks to samcarter(https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter), I finally manage to find proper IDE for my problem. It's Sublime. Downloaded it and installed LaTeX-cwl package as well as LaTeXTools and LATeXYZ package to enable suggestions as I wanted. Works like charm..