# How to disable suggestions when typing \usepackage

Tags: sublime-text

I don't want to see the list of suggestions when typing \usepackage in Latex, aka this thing:

[image: photo]

For reference, I am using Sublime Text 3 with MacTeX distribution and I have package control installed with very few other packages installed currently.

Comment: unrelated to the problem, but can sublime also make suggestions for the documentclass? (this came up in a recent question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/479623/36296)

Comment: Yes, it does, I guess that means I'm asking if these suggestions can be disabled across the board and not just for usepackage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Would you be so kind and add an answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/479623/36296?

Comment: @samcarter I like how a user doesn't have a feature and he wants it, while another user already has the feature but he doesn't want it! Anyway it is only a matter of opinion.

Comment: @JouleV Yes, funny situation. I wonder if it would be helpful to suggest that both users should swap their computers with each other - all problems solved :)